# What to expect in terms of performance from S3 with Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

Planning to store IoT streamed data into S3 and use it for reporting with Athena. Similarly, information related to alarming IoT data will be streamed to S3 as well. The measurements are streamed to s3 every minute for each customer. Alarming info and other metadata make their way to s3 from Dynamo. A measurement record is let's say 4kb and an alarming record is 8kb.

The reports will be generated over years and years' worth of data 7 to 10 years in some cases but mostly over 1 year's worth of data.

Alarmin and IoT data will be partitioned in S3 by customerId and Date.

What should I expect in terms of query performance?

Comment: If you are storing the data in separate files, then the performance will be abysmal. Have you considered streaming to Amazon Kinesis Firehose instead? It can collect and store data in larger files (eg every 5MB or every 5 minutes). Alternatively, you could run a daily job to combine small files into fewer, larger files -- preferably in Snappy-compressed Parquet format.

Comment: we need to report on data up until the last minute. Firehose can slow that down.  @JohnRotenstein

Comment: Then have you considered using Amazon Kinesis Firehose configured to send data to Amazon Redshift? It can be configured for sending batches in short periods of time. See: [Streaming using Kinesis Data Firehose and Redshift | by fact | Medium](https://medium.com/@siprem/streaming-twitter-feed-using-kinesis-data-firehose-and-redshift-745c96d04f58)

Comment: When you say "we need to report on data up until the last minute", does that include the need to report on _historical data_, or are you typically only reporting on "recent data" (and how recent is 'recent')? You could implement a "speed layer". See [Lambda Architecture Overview: What Are the Benefits? | Hazelcast](https://hazelcast.com/glossary/lambda-architecture/) (which is _not_ related to AWS Lambda, it just has a similar name).

Comment: Most reporting on 1 month - 1 year's worth of data But requests can vary for up to multiple years (3-7 )as well.  @JohnRotenstein

Comment: About firehose, it will be at least 1 min buffer, right? I understand it can be overridden if the buffer size is bigger than 1MB which won't be the case for us.

Comment: If you require more immediate results than 1 minute, then you'll likely need to implement a trigger on S3 that calls an AWS Lambda function that inserts the data into a database that you can then query. Amazon Athena will not run well if you have multiple files per minute over a long history.

Comment: I was thinking about running a job that will periodically batch the smaller files in S3 but the readings can stream into s3 directly from Kinesis/dynamo in real-time to avoid the delay. Thoughts? @JohnRotenstein

Comment: That would improve performance. The hard part is combining files and then deleting the files that were combined, without accidentally deleting files that arrive in the meantime. Best done by collecting a list of the files and then combine & delete based on the list rather than what is in the bucket at the time. Possibly move the files to a subdirectory for processing. You can use Athena to select from that directory and use `INSERT INTO` to add it to the 'combined' table.